# ClearCase - find all the files that aren't updated

Tags: unix, clearcase

I'm working with ClearCase on Unix. I am working on a branch, and I want a command that will list all the files which I view on my branch, that have updated versions of them in the Main branch. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the findmerge command to list all the elements that have been modified in another branch.

```
ct findm . -fver /Main -print
```

Comment: I like the `findmerge` option. More precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

A more general command can be used to [find all the files having a version on a given branch](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm#_Toc193967960):

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(my_branch)" -print
```

Comment: while the other answer is more to the point of the question, this is very helpful for me! I wish I could accept two answers... thanks!

Comment: @Amir: you're welcome :) As far as I am concerned, you did choose the right answer.